# PowerShell SQL query using here-string and variable expansion

Tags: sql, powershell

How can I combine the query results for servers that are `swSaturday = 1` and `swSunday = 1`  The `[RebootTime]` could be `swSunBeginTime` or `swSatBeginTime` and it also might not help I'm only trying to run this query on a list of machines in a text file.

Error received is `Exception calling "Fill" with "1" argument(s): "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'."` and the error goes away if `WHERE swName = $($props.Server)` is removed.

```
Function GetServer-RebootLookUp{

Begin{
 $servers = GC D:\Scripts\reboots1.txt
 $SQLServer = 'Server101'
 $Database = 'Database101'
 $SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
 $SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server = $SQLServer; Database = $Database; Integrated Security = True"
}#End Begin

Process{
 $servers | ForEach-Object{
 $props = @{}
 $props.Server = $_

 $ServerQuery = @"
SELECT swName AS [Server], swRack AS [Rack], swEnvironment AS [Environment], swSunBeginTime AS [RebootTime], swSchedule as [Schedule]
FROM SW_SERVICE_LVL
INNER JOIN SW_SPECIALTY
 ON swDiscount = swSpecialtyId
AND swEnvironment IN ( 'Cert', 'Test', 'Prod' )
AND swSchedule IN ( 'SCCM - Monthly' )
AND swGrpResp = 'MyGroup'
AND swRootObjectType = 'Server'
WHERE swSunday = 1
WHERE swName = $($props.Server)
 "@
 $SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
 $SqlCmd.CommandText = $ServerQuery
 $SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection
 $SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
 $SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd
 $DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
 $SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)
 $DataSet.Tables[0]
}
}#end process

End{
 $SqlConnection.Close()
}
}#End function!
GetServer-RebootLookUp
```

Comment: I wonder if you just need some quotes? `WHERE swName = '$($props.Server)'`

Comment: Whoops forgot to add that, I tried that and got the same exception.  I had to change the here-string to `@"` so the variable would expand instead of the `@'` typically used.

Comment: Does it work if you type in the static string that comes from `$($props.Server)`? `WHERE swName = comp1`

Comment: No, but I had a moment of brilliance, I put the expando-variable above as `AND swName IN ( '$($props.Server)' )` and now I get back SOME data.  More brute force interrogation of the server is needed.

Comment: As if i missed that as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your query has two WHERE clauses.  This isn't valid SQL.

Change this:

```
WHERE swSunday = 1
WHERE swName = $($props.Server)
```

To this:

```
WHERE swSunday = 1
    AND swName = $($props.Server)
```

Also, you'll probably need to ensure it's properly quoted as a literal value. In general however, you should use a parameterized query for this sort of thing.

Comment: Strange, doing that made the query loop somehow.